# How to divide pandas column by list of integers based on row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'CITY' : np.random.choice(['PHOENIX','ATLANTA','CHICAGO', 'MIAMI', 'DENVER'], 1000),
                    'DAY': np.random.choice(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'], 1000),
                    'LOCATION' : np.random.choice(['Location1','Location2','Location3', 'Location4', 'Location5'], 1000),
                    'COUNT': np.random.randint(1, 700, size=1000)})

print(df)

         CITY  COUNT        DAY   LOCATION
0      DENVER    521  Wednesday  Location4
1       MIAMI    123   Saturday  Location3
2     ATLANTA    122  Wednesday  Location3
3      DENVER    363   Saturday  Location1
4     PHOENIX    656   Saturday  Location4
5     PHOENIX    369   Saturday  Location3
6       MIAMI    455    Tuesday  Location5
```

How do I divide the count column by a list of integers based on location such as

- if location1 then divide COUNT by 13
- if location2 then divide COUNT by 85
- if location3 then divide COUNT by 42
- if locationx then divide COUNT by intx...

Comment: Is there a reason you won't give a complete example of what you'd like to divide by?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
d = {'Location'+str(i): i*3 for i in range(1, 6)}

df['COUNT'] /= df['LOCATION'].map(d)
```

**Explanation**

1. Define a mapping between "LOCATION" and integer divisor. A dictionary is efficient for this task.
2. Divide "COUNT" column by "LOCATION" column mapped via this dictionary.

Comment: Oh sorry, the integers wouldn't always be in multiples of 3. Actually I just have a list of 6 locations that need to be divided by static integers. Is there a way I could just  manually populate a list?

Comment: @Calculus you can provide any dictionary you'd like.  So long as the values are what you want to divide by and the keys are things you'll find in the `LOCATION` column.  jpp had to provide an example because you didn't.  This answer gives you exactly what you need.  If you require more detail, I'd suggest adding more information to your question.

Comment: @Calculus, as pir explained very well you can provide any mapping you like. If you have specific logic that you do not know how to implement, then feel free to ask.

Comment: I got it now, I didn't realize that was a dictionary. Works as intended. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not well acquainted with `.map()`, so here's my way (which is probably a little more computationally expensive):

`df['COUNT'] = None
locations = {location: to_divide_by, location2: to_divide_by2} # and so on
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df['COUNT'][index] = row['COUNT'] / locations[row['LOCATION']]`